# Inner Join Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join

Estou tentando selecionar dados da tabela modulo através de relacionamento no laravel.
Onde possuo 2 tabelas Modulo e Atividades
Em atividade possuo id_modulo e preciso selecionar uma coluna chamada titulo do modulo através do id.

```
$status = DB::table('atividades')
            ->join('modulos', function ($join) {
                $join->on('modulos.id', '=', 'atividades.id_modulo');
            })
            ->select('modulos.*')
            ->get();
       $status = $status->titulo;
```

Esse script me retorna array vazio.

Comment: Qual versão do laravel você está usando ?

Comment: No banco realmente existem registros e estão relacionados corretamente?

Comment: Se existir mais que um registro na consulta você deve recuperar o valor por array, caso queria o primeiro registro, use `->get()[0]` ou `->first()`

Comment: @PedroHenrique versão 5.8

Comment: @KayoBruno sim o banco possui relacionamento normal entre as tabelas.

Comment: Existe apenas um `modulos.id` para um `atividades.id_modulo` ?

Comment: Sim, @PedroHenrique

Comment: @RichardNicson Pq não usar o Eloquent do Laravel?? O Eloquent irá lhe fornecer meios de acessar essas informações sem precisar fazer join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Quando se usa o `first()`**, você recupera a primeira linha da sua consulta `SQL`, ideal para consultas que retornará apenas um resultado.
- **Quando se usa o `get()`**, você recupera todas as linhas da consulta. (Lembre-se que são necessário fazer um laço no retorno para acessar todas as linhas, mesmo que existe apena um resultado ou informar qual a posição quer recuperar).

No seu caso você está usando o `get()` para trazer seu resultado da consulta, como o `get()` retorna um array é preciso tratar antes de recuperar o valor, caso contrário receberá alguns erros, veja os exemplos abaixo.

- Nesse caso o ideal seria usar o método `first()` que irá retornar o primeiro resultado da consulta.

  ```
  $status = DB::table('atividades')
              ->join('modulos', 'modulos.id', '=', 'atividades.id_modulo')
              ->select('modulos.*')
              ->first();
  $status = $status->titulo;
  ```
- Caso queria continuar usando o método `get()`, antes de recuperar o valor de alguma coluna, deverá informar que deseja acessar a primeira posição do retorno.

  ```
  $status = DB::table('atividades')
              ->join('modulos', 'modulos.id', '=', 'atividades.id_modulo')
              ->select('modulos.*')
              ->get();
  $status = $status[0]->titulo;
  ```

---

Referência: [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries)